# How to scroll old tweets at home page

Tags: twitter

When I do scrolling up at twitter home page, I can see old tweets for up to 2-3 weeks.

To see old tweets of individuals, we can go for Advanced Search.

If I want to see old tweets at home page for up to last 3-4 months back or between certain date range, please let me know, what can I do?

If I can do it, where I can do it, on web or on app?

With Regards
TekQ

Answer (score -2):

Try out Newsfeed option in twitter settings